# Recursively check length of directory name

Tags: bash

I need to determine if there are any directory names > 31 characters in a given directory (i.e. look underneath that root).

I know I can use something like `find /path/to/root/dir -type d >> dirnames.txt`

This will give me a text file of complete paths.

What I need is to get the actual number of characters in each directory name. Not sure if parsing the above results w/sed or awk makes sense. Looking for ideas/thoughts/suggestions/tips on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the length of the directory name only or the complete path?

Answer (score 2):

This short script does it all in one go, i.e. finds all directory names and then outputs any which are greater than 31 characters in length (along with their length in characters):

```
for d in `find  /path/to/root/dir -type d -exec basename {} \;` ; do
  len=$(echo $d | wc -c)
  if [ $len -gt 31 ] ; then
    echo "$d = $len characters"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your dirnames.txt file created by your `find` cmd, you can then sort the data by length of pathname, i.e.

```
 awk '{print length($0) "\t" $0}' dirnames.txt | sort +0nr -1 > dirNamesWithSize.txt
```

This will present the longest path names (based on the value of length) at the top of the file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 find . -type d -exec bash -c '[ $(wc -c <<<"${1##*/}") -gt 32 ] && echo "${1}"' -- {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

The one bug, which I consider minor, is that it will over-count directory name length by 1 every time.

If what you wanted was the whole path rather than the last path component, then use this:

```
find . -type d | sed -e '/.\{32,\}/!d'
```

This version also has a bug, but only when file names have embedded newlines.

The output of both commands is a list of file names which match the criteria. Counting the length of each one is trivial from there.